# Is there any kit for android development?

Tags: kits, android

Is there any kit or board on which I can test out customized android os?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are various, but I'll suggest the [FriendlyArm](http://www.friendlyarm.net/products/mini2440) Mini2440 with 3.5" Display and Touch Panel. See images bellow of the [Sergio Prado's blog](http://www.sergioprado.org/2010/09/12/mini2440-instalando-o-android/):

[image]

Answer (score 10):

You can use a Beagle Board.

http://beagleboard.org/project/android/

http://antipastohw.blogspot.com/2010/10/introducing-diy-android-gadget-starter.html

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure of the cost of the other options, but it may make most sense to just buy an unlocked phone from google as a developer. You can then do what ever you want to the phone including flashing a new OS.

Comment: Yeah, this is definitely the easiest way to get started.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you are going to do *hardware* development, an existing device (phone) will likely be much more convenient and common in the community.  A "customized Android OS" sounds like pure software.

Answer (score 1):

[Embest DevKit8000](http://armkits.com/Product/devkit8000.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Check also the [IGEPv2 board](http://www.igep-platform.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=46&Itemid=55). It has Ethernet and WiFi.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest having a look at a chinese MID. They can be had for 100$ online, but if you have the chance to buy one in china you can get one for around half that price in a copy market. While offering a lower product quality you can get started for a lower price than any development board.
One of the tablets I bought gives me a Wondermedia armv5 compatible processor with 256mb ram and 2gb flash memory which is a way better deal than the friendly arm compatible kit I used at work.

Comment: Do you have the link?